# How to change title of profile-profile2_machine_name only, but not profile-profile2_machine_name/%user

Tags: 7, theming, users

I'd like to change the title of my profile-profile2_machine_name page, but not the page profile-profile2_machine_name/%user page.

This is because I have a settings menu for each user in my profile-profile2_machine_name page and it's a private profile page, while profile-profile2_machine_name/%user is the public profile page.

I've tried many things but when using `arg`, `drupal_get_path_alias()` and `$_GET['q']`, I see that both pages return the same value, which is profile-profile2_machine_name/%user

Comment: By "title", do you mean the <title> metatag, or <h1> title (or something else)?

Comment: It's what drupal_set_title() can achieve. I can change the title but I cannot limit it to the specific page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_override) will do what you need. I have used it on a few projects. It works. And I think it supports wildcards. Also it says it supports tokens.